# Change transfer function in loop - simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I started to use Simulink and I have a question about changing a transfer function using matlab for loop.

Let say I have the following problem:[image]

And my goal is that "system" will be equal to:

[image]

Basically I want to run 5 Simulink simulations from time = 0 to time = 10 for 5 different transfer functions.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: ...`i` is the simulation number, e.g., `i = 1:5`?

Comment: Do you mean to say that `(1 + s*5/i)^i` is the closed-loop transfer function or the "system" transfer function for iteration `i`? Also, I wouldn't use an S-Function, it's unnecessarily complicated for something like that.

Comment: The equation for your system is non-causal.  Are you sure it's correct? (Should the power be -i instead of i?)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood your question, I don't think you need to use Simulink for something like this. The following is my understanding of what you're trying to do, it can be done in plain MATLAB (with the [control system toolbox](https://uk.mathworks.com/products/control.html)):

```
t = 0:1e-3:10;
u = ones(size(t));
y = zeros(5,length(t));
for k=1:5
    H = (1 + tf('s')*5/k)^k; % system transfer function
    CL = 1/((tf('s'))^2*(1-H)); % closed-loop transfer function
    y(k,:) = (lsim(CL,u,t))';
end
plot(t,y)
legend('#1','#2','#3','#4','#5','Location','NorthWest')
grid on
xlabel('Time [s]')
ylabel('Output')
```

which produces the following plot (in Octave). Only the first 2 iterations give a non-zero output:

[image]